# Header doesn't align with decorative line

Tags: vertical-alignment, header-footer

I use `tabular` in header with package `fancyhdr`. I added `settototalheight` to calculate the header height. Following is a small example. The question is that header doesn't align with the decorative line at the right end. But it does at the left end. What is the problem?

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}   
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}
\newcommand{\headertoday}{\the\year \dateseparator \twodigit\month \dateseparator \twodigit\day}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.800000cm,rmargin=1.000000cm,tmargin=2.500000cm,bmargin=1.000000cm]{geometry}

%### define an environment to have a local `\arraystretch'
\newenvironment{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}[1]
  {\def\arraystretch{#1}\tabular}
  {\endtabular}
%#####################################

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand\leftheadercalc[1]{%
\begin{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}{#1}[b]{@{}ll}\footnotesize{Static Calculation Foundation Loads and concrete columns basic parameter}&\footnotesize{}\\\footnotesize{Project: xxxxxx}&\footnotesize{}\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}
}
\newcommand\rightheadercalc[1]{%
\begin{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}{#1}[b]{rr@{}}\footnotesize{Date:}&\footnotesize{\headertoday}\\\footnotesize{Page:}&\footnotesize{\thepage}\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}
}
\newcommand\midheadercalc[1]{%
\begin{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}{#1}[b]{cc}\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\\\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}
}
\settototalheight\headheight{\maxof{\leftheadercalc{0.600000}}{\rightheadercalc{0.600000}}{\midheadercalc{0.600000}}}
\lhead{\leftheadercalc{0.600000}}
\rhead{\rightheadercalc{0.600000}}
\chead{\midheadercalc{0.600000}}

%########## header decorative lines
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi%
\hrule\@height 0.500000pt \@width\headwidth\vskip1.000000pt
\hrule\@height 0.500000pt\@width\headwidth}}    
\makeatother


%########## footer decorative lines
\makeatletter   
\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi%
\hrule\@height 0.500000pt \@width\headwidth\vskip1.000000pt 
\hrule\@height 0.500000pt\@width\headwidth}}    
\makeatother

\newcommand\leftfootercalc[1]{%
\footnotesize{xxx GmbH}
}
\newcommand\rightfootercalc[1]{%
\footnotesize{Document: g-zzz}
}
\newcommand\midfootercalc[1]{%
\footnotesize{Principal: civil eng. yyy}
}
\settototalheight\footskip{\maxof{\leftfootercalc{0.600000}}{\rightfootercalc{0.600000}}{\midfootercalc{0.600000}}}
\lfoot{\leftfootercalc{0.600000}}
\rfoot{\rightfootercalc{0.600000}}
\cfoot{\midfootercalc{0.600000}}

\begin{document}
balala
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for where a space is introduced; an easy way to do that is to enclose
sections of the code with LaTeX3 `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` tags (just include the `expl3` package).

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\rightheadercalc[1]{%
\begin{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}{#1}[b]{rr@{}}\footnotesize{Date:}&\footnotesize{\headertoday}\\\footnotesize{Page:}&\footnotesize{\thepage}\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This corrected the problem on the top right, which by inspection should have had a `%` at the end.

```
\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}%
```

[image]

Same for the bottom footer!

Comment: @Yiannis: due to leave, i can't test your method. from your answer, i found two interesting things. first, use `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`. it looks like syntax check. but it can cancel out redundant space. i will refer to `expl3`'s manual to see what it means. second, add `%` at the end of sentence. what i only know is that `%` just means a comment. but here it means something else more. i will try your answer as soon as i come back. thanks a lot.

Comment: @warem: The `%` is really just a comment, but the line end is taken as a space(!) which is commented out by `%`. Spaces after macros are ignored, but not after `{` or `}`.

Comment: @Yiannis: i am using Miktex 2.4. adding `\usepackage{expl3}` said that file `expl3.sty` not found.

Comment: @Yiannis: if i installed latest `expl3` manually then compiled, i got this error: `Package l3names Error: Required primitive not found: \pdfstrcmp`. after type H for immediately help, i got `LaTeX3 requires the e-TeX primitives and \pdfstrcmp. this is available in pdftex 1.3 or later`. for miktex 2.4, the pdftex version is 3.141592-1.21a. so what's the matter?

Comment: @warem you need to update the MikTeX distribution as you are one version behind on pdftex. If you do not want to, just adding the missing "%" would do the trick.

Comment: @Yiannis: i really hope i can use `expl3` in miktex 2.4. but adding the missing `%` at the end of `\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}` didn't work for me. `%` usually means comment. does it have any other function here?

Comment: @warem you can certainly use expl3 in MikTeX I am using it. Look at more areas where youe may need % see Martin's comment above.

Comment: @Yiannis: my mother tongue is not english. for Martin's comment, does it mean that space after { or } won't be ignored, so i have to add % to comment the space? but i have checked my code, there is no space after any { or }. on the other hand, do you mean that i can use `expl3` in `miktex 2.4` by using the trick `%`?

Comment: @Yiannis, @Martin: i just found that adding `%` at the end of `\end{TabLocalVerticalSpacing}` without using `expl3`, `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` did work. thank you for your hint. but i still didn't understand why it worked. according to Martin's comment, i checked my code and didn't find any space after `{` or `}`. so i still didn't understand `%`'s function here. on the other's hand, i don't know why left header aligned with decorative line at the left end without adding `%` accordingly. i am happy that i can still use miktex 2.4 and don't have to upgrade to a higher version.